# Класс-интерфейс в C++, обязывающий реализовать operator[]

Tags: c++, массивы, наследование, интерфейс, перегрузка-операторов

Нужно/хочу описать одним типом, назовём его `Arraysim`(Массивоподобный), некоторую группу типов, которые определяют `operator[]`. Например, это сырые массивы, `std::vector`, и пользовательский RingBuffer. И использовать, например, так:

```
double funcA( Arraysim& buf ){  // для сырого массива другая функция
    double avg=0;
    for(int i; i<buf.length(); i++)
        avg+=buf[i];
    return avg/buf.length();
}
```

Знаю что есть итераторы, и можно бы их задействовать тут. Однако интересует именно этот синтаксис.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В C++ следует работать с итераторами. То есть лучше, когда класс предоставляет функции `begin` и `end` и `cbegin` и `cend` (по крайней мере для последовательного итератора).

Что касается вашего подхода, то в C++ интерфейсы обычно реализуются с помощью абстрактных базовых классов. Вы можете попробовать следующее

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
struct ISubscript
{
    virtual T & operator []( size_t ) = 0;
    virtual const T & operator []( size_t ) const = 0;
};

class Arraysim : public ISubscript<double>
{
public:
    double & operator []( size_t n ) override
    {
        return a[n];
    }        

    const double & operator []( size_t n ) const override
    {
        return a[n];
    }        

    size_t length() const { return N; }

private:
    enum : size_t { N = 10 };
    double a[N];
};

double funcA( const Arraysim &buf )
{
    double avg = 0;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < buf.length(); i++ ) avg += buf[i];

    return avg / buf.length();
}

int main()
{
    Arraysim a;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < a.length(); i++ ) a[i] = i + i / 10.0;

    std::cout << funcA( a ) << std::endl;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль:

```
4.95
```

По крайней мере это компилируется.:)

Будет правильным еще включить функцию `length` в класс интерфейса. Более наглядный пример, когда функция `funcA` также является шаблонной и имеет параметр ссылочного типа `ISubscript`, то есть когда функция имеет дело непосредственно с интерфейсом, а не с конкретным классом, реализующим данный интерфейс, следующий

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
struct ISubscript
{
    virtual T & operator []( size_t ) = 0;
    virtual const T & operator []( size_t ) const = 0;
    virtual size_t length() const = 0;
};

class Arraysim : public ISubscript<double>
{
public:
    double & operator []( size_t n ) override
    {
        return a[n];
    }        

    const double & operator []( size_t n ) const override
    {
        return a[n];
    }        

    size_t length() const override { return N; }

private:
    enum : size_t { N = 10 };
    double a[N];
};

template <class T>
T funcA( const ISubscript<T> &buf )
{
    T avg = 0;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < buf.length(); i++ ) avg += buf[i];

    return avg / buf.length();
}

int main()
{
    Arraysim a;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < a.length(); i++ ) a[i] = i + i / 10.0;

    std::cout << funcA( a ) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: ужас.............

Comment: @zenden2k Что вы увидели ужасного?

Comment: почему вы пишете `enum { N = 10 }`? Не `const int N=10`.

Comment: @kyb  Если эта константа - член класса, то она должна быть объявлена как static. Иначе компилятор выдаст сообщение об ошибке при объявлении массива. Объявление перечисления не увеличивает размер класса.

Comment: @kyb Я добавил еще базовый тип для перечисления.:)

Comment: Только традиционнее не `length`, а `size`.